# What back end tech to use for a 2-player, turn based, ajax web game?: Python or Java, FastCGI or app server?

Tags: java, python, ajax, web-applications

I'm building a web based 2 player game, client side interface will all be done in an ajax manor with html/css/javascript. I want clients to be able to initiate games and join others, chat etc, but I'm stuck on what the best way to code and communicate with the server is, I would like to use either Java or Python.

Python via FastCGI seems to be more widely accommodated for on hosting providers?

What are the advantages in this case for using a java/python web app like tomcat or django as apposed to taking the fastgci route and what combination would you recommend?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Use what allows your app to be hosted where you want to host it, and what you're the most comfortable with.

Comment: I think this is definitely backwards. Instead, you should use the appropriate technology and choose a hosting provider that supports it.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Use what you know best.  Toss a coin.  Heads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some direct benefits of using Django instead of rolling your own

- Database ORM
- Templating
- User authentication
- Pluggable applications (use other people's stuff, yay!)

Also, Django can be deployed as a FCGI application.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going for django on google's app engine for now :)